# transformer in chain can be invoked channel for logging?

Tags: spring-integration

```
<chain input-channel="afiHeadToHeaderChannel" output-channel="simResMsgOutBoundChannel">
    <transformer ref="afiHeadToHeaderTransform" />
    **<transformer ref="fixedToMapTransform"**  
    <transformer ref="simReqResTransform" />
    <transformer ref="mapToFixedTransform" />
    <transformer ref="headerToAfiHeadTransform" />
</chain>
```

After executing transformer "fixedToMapTransform", I want to log using Message.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Spring Integration-"native" way to do it (as Gary pointed) but you can write your own logging activator.

```
<chain input-channel="afiHeadToHeaderChannel" output-channel="simResMsgOutBoundChannel">
    <transformer ref="afiHeadToHeaderTransform" />
    <transformer ref="fixedToMapTransform"/>
    <service-activator ref="loggingActivator" method="handleMessage" />
    <transformer ref="simReqResTransform" />
    <transformer ref="mapToFixedTransform" />
    <transformer ref="headerToAfiHeadTransform" />
</chain>

<beans:bean id="loggingActivator" class="com.mycompany.LoggingActivator" />
```

and the activator code:

```
public class LoggingActivator {
  private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(LoggingActivator.class);

  public Message< ? > handleMessage(final Message< ? > message) {
    LOG.debug(message);
    return message;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't; endpoints within a chain are connected with anonymous channels. You would have to break your chain into two, with the output channel of the first being the input channel of the second; then, you can wire-tap that channel.

A chain is a "black box".

Comment: Not exactly ;) He can't use logging-channel-adapter of course (from the reason you've mentioned), but he can write its own handler.